# Java - from a class within a project, check if a file exists in a different project

Tags: java, file, project, exists

I am within a project cd.ef.gh/country/terms/license/CreateLicense.java

From the class CreateLicense.java, I want to check if a file exists in a different project.
However the below code always return falls

```
File newfile = new File(uv.wx.yz/legal/expiry/notice/readme.txt) 
if(newfile.exists()) // this always returns false , even though the readme.txt file is exactly at that location.
```

I am apparently missing a simple thing or overlooking something obvious here

Please help

Thanks

Comment: second project (build) is in classpath of first project ?

Comment: No, it is not. Is that why this is not working ? Any work around ?